# How do I run my Console Application code within a Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a Console Application with C# in VS.

I want to make a button, which runs some code. In this case, what I wrote in the Console Application. How would one go about that?

Basically I want to create a set of buttons, where each executes a specific task.
How would I do this? How can I take that code I created earlier and have a button execute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can mention **two options of many**:

1. Deal with your Console app as a DLL and reference it in your WinForm Runner App.
2. Deal with your Console app as an EXE file and run it using `Process.Start`.

The first option will give you the ability to reach the methods **while** the second one will deal with it as a totally separate app with all its functionalities as a single application.

**Example of the Second Option:**

1. Create a Solution with three projects as in the screenshot below.

[image: Solution]

2. Suppose your Console App 1 code is

```
    using System;
        namespace SOC.ConsoleApp01
        {
            public class Program
            {
                public static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Written from Console App 1");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

While the second is

```
using System;

namespace SOC.ConsoleApp02
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Written from Console App 2");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

3. Now build the Console App1 and Console App 2 by **right click** on **each of** them in the solution explorer and click **Build** or **ReBuild**.
   [image: Build]

This will result in execution files generated like in the following screenshots:
[image: App 1 Exe file]
[image: App 2 Exe file]

4. In your WinForm Project write the code of Subject buttons like this

```
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace SO.Console.Apps.Runner
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(@"C:\REPOS\SO.Console.Apps.Runner\SOC.ConsoleApp01\bin\Debug\SOC.ConsoleApp01.exe");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(@"C:\REPOS\SO.Console.Apps.Runner\SOC.ConsoleApp02\bin\Debug\SOC.ConsoleApp02.exe");
        }
    }
    }
```

the result is
[image: Result]